# How do I change the index in a csv file to a proper time format?

Tags: r, csv

I have a CSV file of 1000 daily prices

They are of this format:

```
1    1.6
2    2.5
3    0.2
4     ..
5     ..
6
7     ..
.
.
1700 1.3
```

The index is from 1:1700

**But I need to specify a begin date and end date this way:**

Start period is lets say, 25th january 2009
and the last 1700th value corresponds to 14th may 2013

So far Ive gotten this close to this problem:

```
> dseries <- ts(dseries[,1], start = ??time??, freq = 30)
```

How do I go about this? thanks

UPDATE:
managed to create a seperate object with dates as suggested in the answers and plotted it, but the y axis is weird, as shown in the screenshot
[image]

Comment: Are dates starting with `25th january 2009` sequential 1 day at a time? It it is then 1700th date is `20/09/2013` not `14 may 2013`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

`as.Date("25-01-2009",format="%d-%m-%Y") + (seq(1:1700)-1)`

A **better** way, thanks to @AnandaMahto:

`seq(as.Date("2009-01-25"), by="1 day", length.out=1700)`

Plotting:

```
df <- data.frame(
  myDate=seq(as.Date("2009-01-25"), by="1 day", length.out=1700),
  myPrice=runif(1700)
                    )

plot(df)
```

Comment: @AnandaMahto Wow, this is crazy!

Comment: hey zx, ive managed to create another list with 1700 dates now, worked great. Could you help me complete it by telling me how I should plot the values on each day against the date in a time series now?

Comment: Ive now got one object with a column of prices and another object with your dates in a sequence

Comment: hey dont both ive managed to do it, i used plot(date,mseries[,2])
my y axis is acting weird though; my values are all between -1 and 2 but on the plot it goes all the way upto 800? any hints?

Comment: @AnandaMahto hey could you take a look at my updated screenshot? ive still got the problem

Answer (score 2):

R stores Date-classed objects as the integer offset from "1970-01-01" but the `as.Date.numeric` function needs an offset ('origin') which can be any staring date:

```
rDate <- as.Date.numeric(dseries[,1], origin="2009-01-24")
```

Testing:

```
> rDate <- as.Date.numeric(1:10, origin="2009-01-24")
> rDate
 [1] "2009-01-25" "2009-01-26" "2009-01-27" "2009-01-28" "2009-01-29"
 [6] "2009-01-30" "2009-01-31" "2009-02-01" "2009-02-02" "2009-02-03"
```

You didn't need to add the extension `.numeric` since R would automticallly seek out that function if you used the generic stem, `as.Date`, with an integer argument. I just put it in because `as.Date.numeric` has different arguments than `as.Date.character`.

Comment: (+1'ed)thanks Dwin, your answer was perfect I wish i could accept both your answers